# Program a macro that invoke another App elements

Tags: xamarin.android

I would like to write a program or app that interact with another App installed on android.
I got just to open the App, but now I would like to get programmatically all the elements in the actual GUI of this app and interact with its invoking its.
Is is possible to do something like this? I would awoid to use monekeyRunnner as I need to build some decisional logic, or would you recommend to use anther existing tool that build a macro?

Comment: Does the `another App` created by you or some one else?

Comment: Hello, is created by someone else. I looks I can only simulate a touch without knowledge of elements in the code. There is nothing allowig me to access the public elements of another app.

Comment: We do not suggest to control or do something for the app created by someone else.